# this.http.delete is not returning success message or not displaying any error message

Tags: mysql, angular, rest, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I am using Spring boot, Rest and angular in my project which displays employess details for fetching, edit, Delete and Add New. I am unable to get any success or error message when I clicked on DELETE button using ng2 Table.

```
protected emitOnRemoved(element: Row) {    

const options = {   
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })      
}  
  var err : any;
  console.log("user to delete:" + "1711111");
  let url = 'http://localhost:Port/someEmployees/1711111';   

    console.log("url "+url);
    return this.http.delete(url,options).subscribe(data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('yay'));
```

}

Comment: Check the network tab to see what request is sent and the response

Comment: probably you get 204, no content

Comment: I am unable to see any Request Method: DELETE in network tab. But in above code , I am able fetch the contents of which I selected for deletion using   console.log("emit on Removed Values "+Object.values(element));

Comment: Actually in my project, I am not deleting the entire row.... I am making Status column as Inactive using rest

Comment: Can some one help me finding the mistake i did. How to make this work

Comment: this.http.delete not calling the delete service...... what can I do to make it work